# How to show only deletions on git history

Tags: git

I need to see one file from git history, but I don't remember what exacty was its name. So, how to find out about file deletions in repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see all the changesets that have removed files along with the files they have removed using the following command:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

It should then be possible to use grep (or something else) on the output to find the file you are looking for